# $G$ acts as a group of automorphisms on $A$, $\textrm{Spec}(A^G)=G \backslash \textrm{Spec}(A)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}$
I'm starting to read about quotients of group schemes and am working through some basic exercises.  This is from *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* by Qing Liu.  I'm trying to figure out part (a).

[image]

I want to show that if $\mathfrak P_1, \mathfrak P_2$ are primes of $A$ with $\mathfrak P_1 \cap A^G = \mathfrak P_2 \cap A^G$, then $\mathfrak P_1 = \sigma \mathfrak P_2$ for some $\sigma \in G$.

Since $A$ is integral over $R:=A^G$ by part (b), the problem becomes to show that for any prime $\mathfrak p$ of $R$, the group $G$ acts transitively on the primes in $A$ lying over $\mathfrak p$.

If we just stick to maximal ideals, I can solve the problem by modifying an argument from basic algebraic number theory:

**Solution when $\mathfrak p$ is a maximal ideal**: Since $R \subseteq A$ is integral, every prime lying over $\mathfrak p$ is also maximal.  Let $\mathfrak P, \mathfrak Q$ be distinct primes of $A$ lying over $\mathfrak p$.  Suppose that $\mathfrak P \neq \sigma \mathfrak P$ for any $\sigma \in G$.  Then $\mathfrak P$ and $\sigma \mathfrak Q$ are comaximal ideals for every $\sigma \in G$, and so by the Chinese remainder theorem there exists a solution $x \in A$ to the system

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{\mathfrak P}$$

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{\sigma^{-1}\mathfrak Q} : \sigma \in G $$

Then $\sigma(x) - 1 \in \mathfrak Q$ for all $\sigma$, so $\sigma(x)$ is never in $\mathfrak Q$.  Hence neither is $y := \prod\limits_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x)$.  But $y \in \mathfrak P \cap A^G = \mathfrak p \subseteq \mathfrak Q$, contradiction.  $\blacksquare$

I had an idea of how to reduce to the case where $\mathfrak p$ is maximal.  Let $S = R - \mathfrak p$.  Then the inclusion $R \subseteq A$ induces an injective ring homomorphism $R_{\mathfrak p} = R\otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p} \rightarrow A \otimes_R R_{\mathfrak p} = S^{-1}A$.  By tensoring with $1_{R_{\mathfrak p}}$, we still get an action of $G$ as a group of automorphisms of the ring $S^{-1}A$.

If I can show that $R_{\mathfrak p} = (S^{-1}A)^G$, then I will be in the same situation as before, with $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$ a maximal ideal.

From the diagram

$$\begin{array} \textrm{Spec } A & \leftarrow & \Spec S^{-1}A \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \Spec A^G & \leftarrow  &\Spec (A^G)_{\mathfrak p} \end{array}$$

with horizontal injections and vertical surjections, with the action of $G$ on the top right object being the restriction of the action on the top left, I'll get the result.

Answer (score 3):

Nvm figured it out.  Clearly $R_{\mathfrak p} \subseteq (S^{-1}A)^G$.  Conversely, suppose $\frac{a}{s} = \frac{\sigma(a)}{s}$ for all $\sigma \in G$.  Then there exists $s_{\sigma} \in A^G \setminus \mathfrak p$ such that $\sigma(a)ss_{\sigma} = a s s_{\sigma}$ for all $\sigma \in G$.

Let $t = s \prod\limits_{\sigma \in G} s_{\sigma}$.  Then $at \in A^G$, since

$$\tau(at) = \tau(a)ss_{\tau} \prod\limits_{\sigma \neq \tau} s_{\sigma} = ass_{\tau} \prod\limits_{\sigma \neq \tau} = at$$

with $\frac{a}{s} = \frac{at}{st}$.